# How to check weather string contains backslash?

Tags: java, string

I want to check if a string contains "\" or not. I used the string method contains(), but its not working

```
String path = "D:\steve\";
if(path.contains("\"){
    path = path.replaceAll("\\\\","");
}
```

Comment: While in this case it's easy enough to guess what's going on, in future please give more details than "it's not working" - specify the exact error, whether it's a compile-time error or an exception, and where it occurs.

Answer (score 2):

Use escape character `\`

```
public class test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "a\\b";
        System.out.println(str.contains("\\"));
    }
}
```

> A character preceded by a backslash (`\`) is an escape sequence and has
>   special meaning to the compiler.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html